# What is time consuming using Dotfuscator?

Tags: .net, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I have to obfuscate a large solution (~200 assemblies) using Dotfuscator Pro 4.10. The last run took ~4hr, and this is quite long, much longer than the build itself. What is so time consuming? I mean, I can modify my settings. Maybe I ask it to perform a job that takes a very long time but is not essential to me.

Any idea?

Thanks.

**Update**: my code is in C++/CLI with native calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things you can try:

- Don’t run the build in the Dotfuscator GUI.  Instead, run at the command line or with MSBuild.
- On the Settings tab > Global Options, under General, set the Build Progress to “Quiet”.
- On the Settings tab > Reports > Smart Obfuscation, set the Report Verbosity to “Warnings Only”.

Comment: Hi @Nate Allen, I switched to Quiet & Warning Only and I observe a gain of 15% for a small set of projects. This is good because 15% of 230 min is 35 min.... ;-) ...

Comment: ... but what do you mean by "running the build"? You mean running Dotfuscator? I start it from command line, of course. The GUI is....... special! B-)) (but it is my opinion only!)

Comment: Yes, by "running the build" I meant running Dotfuscator.  There may be other things you can do to reduce the Dotfuscator build time, but these would require in-depth analysis (not suitable for a public forum).  If you have support from PreEmptive, you could contact support for more help.  Disclaimer:  I am employed by PreEmptive.

Comment: Yeah, You're a SO member for 1 year and you answer only Dotfuscator question so I guessed you were a PreEmptive employee. ;-) Many thanks for the help!